# Scrapy seems to have installed, but when checking for version I get "No module named scrapy"

Tags: python, installation, scrapy, command-prompt

I have the dependencies installed (openssl, lxml, pyopenssl, twisted matrix, etc...) and when I type in the command

```
easy_install Scrapy
```

it seems to work, and gives me this output

```
Searching for scrapy
Best match: scrapy 0.24.2
Processing scrapy-0.24.2-py2.7.egg
scrapy 0.24.2 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing scrapy script to C:\Users\Joel\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\Sc
ripts
Installing scrapy.bat script to C:\Users\Joel\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\Use
r\Scripts

Using c:\users\joel\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\lib\site-packages\scrapy
-0.24.2-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for scrapy
Finished processing dependencies for scrapy
```

however, when I check the version of scrapy it gives me this error

```
C:\python27\python.exe: No module named scrapy
```

how do I install scrapy? I would like to scrape the web...

EDIT: when using

```
pip install scrapy
```

i get this error
    ****************************************************************************

---

```
WARNING:

        An optional code optimization (C extension) could not be compiled.

        Optimizations for this package will not be available!
()
Could not find Visual Studio 2008 in your path.

If you do not have Visual Studio 2008 installed, you can use
the MinGW compiler instead. To install mingw, do:
    enpkg mingw
To use the MinGW compiler to build an extension module, use
the '-c' flag, e.g.:
    python setup.py build_ext -c mingw64
Note that building Python extensions with MinGW is not officially
supported, although it is known to work in many cases.
****************************************************************************
```

---

I have installed visual studio 2008 so maybe my path isnt pointing there? if so what do I need to add as an environmental variable so it sees it?

Comment: Is `c:\users\joel\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\lib\site-packages` in your `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: It should be in `sys.path`, but you shouldn't need to add it to `PYTHONPATH` to get it there

Answer (score 0):

It seems possible, since you appear to have loaded the Enthought distribution, that the `easy_install` you ran used a different Python from the one you get when you use the "python" command (i.e one runs the Enthought distribution, one runs your system-installed Python, which eceryone except Alex gaynor should leave strictly alone). You should be able to check this with `which easy_install` and `which python` commands.

If they do appear to be related to the same Python executable I am a little at a loss.

Comment: If I remember correctly, Python utilities under Windows generally install in a `scripts` subdirectory of the associated Python installation, but it's been a while ...

Comment: `which <something>` might not help, since OP is on Windows

Comment: is there a way to check this with windows?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have all of the correct dependencies?

- Environment variables
- OpenSSL
- Visual C++

Check this link and let us know how you are checking the version and what errors you are getting.
http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html#intro-install-platform-notes

It looks like you are installing to the correct version of Python, but you can always try

```
easy_install-2.7 scrapy
```

Comment: I tried it and i got the same answer. can you look at the above edit though?